# Proper dependecy tracking in a custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-databinding

What I'm trying to achieve is to **visually filter table rows generated by the `foreach` binding** in a way that `tr` elements of the rows that are filtered out would be hidden instead of removed from the DOM.
This approach significantly improves rendering performance when a user changes filter conditions. This is why I don't want the `foreach` to be bound to a computed observable array which is updated depending on the filter condition.
I want this solution to be a ready-to-use building block that I can use in other places of the project.

As far as I'm familiar with Knockout, the best way is to implement a custom binding.

The way I intended to use this binding is something like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: unfilteredItems, visibilityFilter: itemsFilter">
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

where `itemsFilter` is a function returning `boolean` depending of whether current row should be visible or not, like this:

```
    self.itemsFilter = function (item) {
        var filterFromDate = filterFromDate(), // Observable
            filterDriver = self.filterDriver(); // Observable too

        return item && item.Date >= filterFromDate && (!filterDriver || filterDriver === item.DriverKey);
    };
```

Here is the binding implementation that I have so far:

```
/*
 * Works in conjunction with the 'foreach' binding and allows to perform fast filtering of generated DOM nodes by
 * hiding\showing them rather than inserting\removing DOM nodes.
*/
ko.bindingHandlers.visibilityFilter = {
    // Ugly thing starts here
    init: function (elem, valueAccessor) {
        var predicate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        predicate();
    },
    // Ugly thing ends
    update: function (elem, valueAccessor) {
        var predicate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            child = ko.virtualElements.firstChild(elem),
            visibleUpdater = ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update,
            isVisible,
            childData,
            trueVaueAccessor = function () { return true; },
            falseVaueAccessor = function () { return false; };

        while (child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                childData = ko.dataFor(child);

                if (childData) {
                    isVisible = predicate(childData, child);
                    visibleUpdater(child, isVisible ? trueVaueAccessor : falseVaueAccessor);
                }
            }

            child = ko.virtualElements.nextSibling(child);
        }
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.visibilityFilter = true;
```

Do you see that ugly `init` part with predicate invocation without passing an object to it?

Without this, if there is no rows generated by the `foreach` binding by the first time Knockout calls the `update` method, `itemsFilter` filter function wouldn't be called.
Hence, no observables would be read and KO dependency tracking mechanism decides that this binding doesn't depend on any observables in my view model.
And when values of the filter observables (`filterFromDate` and `filterDriver`) get changed, the `update` will never be called again and the whole filtering doesn't work.

**How can I improve this implementation (or the whole approach to the problem) in order to not make that ugly call to the filter function** which at least makes the function await an `undefined` value as a paramenter?

Comment: It seems like you could just use a `visible` binding on the `tr` element.

Comment: @Roy: Which observables do I need to bind it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `visible` binding on the `tr` and bind it to the result of a function call using `$data` as the parameter. A little demo below. Whichever value you select is filtered out of the table.

```js
var vm = {
  rows: ko.observableArray(['One', 'Two', 'Three']),
  selected: ko.observable('One'),
  isVisible: function(row) {
    return row !== vm.selected();
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options:rows, value:selected"></select>
<table border="1" data-bind="foreach:rows">
  <tr data-bind="visible:$parent.isVisible($data)">
    <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is really much simplier approach and it works like a charm! Thank you! Very appreciate your help!