# Custom binding(?) that adds some standard Knockout bindings to child nodes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding

**I want to implement using Knockout something easily reusable (probably, custom binding) that could apply mix of standard bindings: the `foreach` binding to a `tbody` node and another standard bindings (`visible` and `css`) to its `tr` child nodes.**

AFAIK, the best way it can be achieved is to write a custom binding.
I want to use it like that:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="tableRows: { rows: unfilteredItems, filter: rowFilter }">
        <tr data-bind="possibly, some hard coded bindings including visible and css bindings">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

, where `unfilteredItems` and `rowFilter` are some `observables`.

I want the custom binding to 'transform' this into the following and let KO process this as it was initially in the layout:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: unfilteredItems">
        <tr data-bind="visible: rowFilter($data), css: rowClass($data), and now hard coded bindings, if any">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here `rowClass()` is a function contained in the component and just returns a string that should be appended to the `tr`'s `class` attribute based on the current `$data`.

I know how to apply the `foreach` binding to the node that my binding is applied to:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tableRows = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = valueAccessor(),
            rows = options.rows;

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: rows }, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

This part is working perfectly.

But I can't find anywhere **how to add bindings to the child `tr` nodes, so that when the `foreach` binding would process child nodes, that bindings (and all bindings that already contained in the child layout) were applied to and processed in the same manner as they were initially in the layout.**

I could try to manually add the required bindings to the child `tr` nodes as a string in the `init` function using JS DOM API, but I have feeling that it should be cleaner solution using some KO API.

Also, I need the custom binding to properly handle cases when there initially are another bindings on the `tr` nodes including both `visible` and `css` bindings.

My project uses Knockout 2.2.1 and it would be nice if the solution doesn't rely on the Knockout 3 features, if possible.

Could someone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: You should probably update the question and turn the code into an actual repro where the final bold part (the actual question?) is the *only* thing not working yet. Otherwise we have to be *guessing* at the missing pieces, making it very hard to give a definitive answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to modify the `data-bind` attributes of the inner elements of the `foreach` using [jQuery's `data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) or similar. The outer would be processed by Knockout before its inner parts would. I haven't tried such things myself.

In fact, since you're just doing boilerplate-rewrite, you could use jQuery to find and rewrite the tags before you apply Knockout bindings at all. That would save you the custom binding handler.

Comment: Thank you! I'll leave this approach as a last resort in case of there is no suitable KO API or technique to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own tr template for `foreach` binding like

```
<script type="text/html" id="rowTemplate">

    <tr data-bind="css:{'success': $root.rowClass($data)}, visible: $root.rowFilter($data)">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>

</script>
```

and render it inside your custom binding as

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {template:{foreach: data, name: "rowTemplate"}}, bindingContext);
return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem here is that the child layout of the `tr` isn't known prior and is different across the project. I don't know how to address it with this solution.